# Basics of Linked List

Tags: java, pointers, memory, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to understand the basics of Linked List. The definition of my LinkedList class is as follows:

```
 public class ListNode {
 int val;
 ListNode next;
 ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
```

Now I am facing a problem. My code is as follows:

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
dummy.next =  head;
ListNode prev = dummy;
ListNode slow = head;
head.next = null;
prev.next = slow;

ListNode temp = slow.next;
prev.next = temp;

System.out.println(dummy.next); //comes out null
```

Why is it coming out as null? `dummy.next` was pointing to head and I only changed `slow` and `prev`?

EDIT:

Can we use `slow` and `head` interchangeably? If yes, then why does this happen?

```
// head points to a Linked list starting from 1 in 1 -> 2 -> 3
ListNode curr = head;

while(curr.next!= null){
    curr= curr.next;
}

System.out.println(curr);
System.out.println(head); //these are different and head does not change
```

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51110381/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93668/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `dummy` to point to the same object as `head`. Then later, you do  `head.next = null;` Since `dummy` and `head` reference the same object, `dummy.next` is also null.

EDIT:

Upon looking at your code further, I found the problem.

I will paste your code in with line numbers for easier reference.

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0); // Line 1
dummy.next =  head; // Line 2
ListNode prev = dummy; // Line 3
ListNode slow = head; // Line 4
head.next = null; // Line 5
prev.next = slow; // Line 6

ListNode temp = slow.next; // Line 7
prev.next = temp; // Line 8

System.out.println(dummy.next); // Line 9
```

Lines 3-4: Now `prev` points to the same object as `dummy`, and same for `slow` and `head`. We can essentially use these "names" interchangeably.

Line 5: Setting `head`'s next to null

Line 6: Same as running: `dummy.next = head`

Line 7: `temp` now points to `head`'s next (since `slow` and `head` are the same). Remember, `head`'s next is null (line 5). Basically, this means `temp` is null.

Line 8: Same as `dummy.next
 = temp`. Since temp is null, **this is where you are setting `dummy`'s next to null**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I actually had dummy.next = head and not dummy = head.

Comment: Where are you first initializing the `dummy` variable?

Comment: Hi Beobe! I have edited the question to answer your concern. Thanks for replying!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: I am really getting confused by all this.

Comment: @crazyy_photonn I found the problem. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the extremely detailed explanation. With regards to the explanation that you provide, I have a doubt, 
The code is as follows: 
Suppose the head points to a linked list 1 -> 2 -> 3. Head is the node with value 1. 

Now, ListNode curr = head;
        
    while(curr.next!= null){
        curr= curr.next;
    }
        
    System.out.println(curr);
    System.out.println(head);

These two are different. If we can use curr and head interchangeably, why does this show different outputs?

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect my confusions? I hope it is more clear what I ask. Please feel free to ask if anything doesnt make sense. Thanks!

Comment: I only said we could use `curr` and `head` interchangeably because you initially define the variable `curr` to **point to** the same object that `head` is pointing to. If you did `curr.val = 5;`, then you would see that `head.val` has also been changed to 5. `head` and `curr` are two ways of referencing the same underlying object. **But**, in your while loop, you are reassigning `curr`. This means it will no longer point to the same object that `head` is pointing to.

Comment: Ohh!! This actually does makes sense. Thank you so very much for clearing this out for me! I will accept your answer. Thanks once again!